# Random crashes from Cocos2d actions

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I'm getting a few inconsistent crashes whenever some CCAction is being applied to a sprite.

Ex: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:scale:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1860a4'`

I get the same thing with CCBlink sometimes too. The actions are being called from inside a scheduler (using a BOOL flag to make sure they only run once).

Any ideas on why I'm getting these kind of errors? Its very inconsistent. Thanks

Comment: how you define the fish variable ? what type is it ? can you post the scheduler code as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got NSInvalidArgumentException. Make sure that you pass needed values to the method. For example, that you don't try pass BOOL value when method waits for float, etc.

Comment: I'm passing static values that don't change at all. Any further ideas? Thanks!

Comment: [fish runAction:
         [CCSequence actions:
          [CCBlink actionWithDuration:0.5 blinks:3],
          [CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:0.9],
          nil]];

Comment: hmm... really i have no suggestions in that case =( sorry. one thing, maybe header is not imported.. i mean "CCActionInterval.h"

Comment: Probably best to just import cocos2d.h.  It is a strange bug you're seeing.  Please post back if you find out why.